# Link changing other CSS with classes

Tags: jquery

Changing all same classe (count) for css effect with same and other classes.

HTML:

```
<a class="imghover1" href="/en/?p=1">one</a>
<a class="imghover2" href="/en/?p=2">two</a>
<a class="imghover3" href="/en/?p=3">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->
<a class="imgval imghover1" href="/en/?p=1"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/one.svg">one</a>
<a class="imgval imghover2" href="/en/?p=2"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/two.svg">two</a>
<a class="imgval imghover3" href="/en/?p=3"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/three.svg">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->
```

This jQuery code not working I try to use for():

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    totincr= $(".imgval").length;

    for(var incr=1; incr < totincr; incr++){
        $('.imghover'+incr).hover(
            function(){ 
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr+' img').removeClass('img-gray'); 
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr).addClass('img-text-color'); 
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr).removeClass('no-underline'); 
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr+' img').css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr).css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
            },
            function(){ 
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr+' img').addClass('img-gray');
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr).removeClass('img-text-color'); 
                $('.imgval.imghover'+incr).addClass('no-underline'); 
            }
        );
    }      
});
```

this code works, 
but I need to create one "imghover" with number per element :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.imghover1').hover(
        function(){ 
            $('.imgval.imghover1 img').removeClass('img-gray'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover1').addClass('img-text-color'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover1').removeClass('no-underline'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover1 img').css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
            $('.imgval.imghover1').css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
        },
        function(){ 
            $('.imgval.imghover1 img').addClass('img-gray');
            $('.imgval.imghover1').removeClass('img-text-color'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover1').addClass('no-underline'); 
        }
    );

    $('.imghover2').hover(
        function(){ 
            $('.imgval.imghover2 img').removeClass('img-gray'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover2').addClass('img-text-color'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover2').removeClass('no-underline'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover2 img').css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
            $('.imgval.imghover2').css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
        },
        function(){ 
            $('.imgval.imghover2 img').addClass('img-gray');
            $('.imgval.imghover2').removeClass('img-text-color'); 
            $('.imgval.imghover2').addClass('no-underline'); 
        }
    );       
    // and more...  
});
```

I try to use .each() or (for) but It's not working.
Any solution?

Comment: Why are you not simply using CSS for this? In 22 years of web development I have never needed to use a Javascript-based hover.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write on hover for each anchor tag. You can make use of start of attribute select using `^`, which will pick all `a` element having class name start with `imghover`. You can use hovered anchor tag class name to find the related elements and make hover effect.

see below code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a[class^=imghover]').hover(
        function(){ 
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            var $image = $('.imgval.' + className + ' img');
            var $anchor = $('.imgval.' + className);
            $image.removeClass('img-gray'); 
            $anchor.addClass('img-text-color').removeClass('no-underline'); 
            $image.css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
            $anchor.css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
        },
        function(){ 
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            var $image = $('.imgval.' + className + ' img');
            var $anchor = $('.imgval.' + className);
            $image.addClass('img-gray');
            $anchor.removeClass('img-text-color').addClass('no-underline'); 
        }
    );
 });
```

```css
.img-gray {color: gray;}
.img-text-color {color: red;}
.no-underline {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="imghover1" href="/en/?p=1">one</a>
<a class="imghover2" href="/en/?p=2">two</a>
<a class="imghover3" href="/en/?p=3">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->
<a class="imgval imghover1" href="/en/?p=1"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/one.svg">one</a>
<a class="imgval imghover2" href="/en/?p=2"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/two.svg">two</a>
<a class="imgval imghover3" href="/en/?p=3"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/three.svg">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->
```

NOTE: I have added temporary CSS classes just to know if element are adding / removing classes properly

Comment: autoptimize_Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at autoptimize_bb4c7263ad5fe5d1e89e293823436dea.js:36

Comment: i don't know the exact CSS you are using but i have put colors for different css so that change effect can be seen. You can regenerate the issue on code snippet or jsfiddle using my code and then we can take a look at it

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchOffAutoHideShow' of undefined

Comment: use`jQuery(document).ready(function($){` instead of `$(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: CSS3 HTML5 and the last of jquery

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchOffAutoHideShow' of undefined`  - you must be using some third party js for this, check that

Comment: no error with jQuery(document).ready(function($){
but no result...

Comment: You can see, color changing for respective element of the hovered element in my code snippet so basic logic is working. We need to see how you have integrated this code on your end. It would be good if you can reproduce your issue on jsfiddle or code snippet

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` is working in code snippet i posted. There could be some console error, please check that

Comment: can you inspect the element and check if css applied or not

Comment: works it was because I use one other class: <a class="nolink imghover1"

Comment: I fact not work proprely, if I have a other class inside like class="other imghover1" there not working and not work on hover when I am on the same element class="imgval imghover1"... (if you are hover the second link one two three)

Comment: the problem is "className"

Comment: are there multiple classess in the anchor which we clicked?

Comment: yes, when you are on mouse hover on the green link, the color was not changing in red, but work with the blue link, the color change in red. (try with the snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I fact not work proprely, if I have a other class inside like class="other imghover1" there not working and not work on hover when I am on the same element class="imgval imghover1"... (if you are hover the second link one two three)

I try with [class*=imghover] but same result, the content don't change if you have more classes...

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each `<a>` anchor tag and check if it's attribute class contains `imghover` keyword or not using `indexOf` JS function. If classlist contains the word then next single character(1,2,3,etc.) of `imghover` will be added.

**Here is the Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var imgHover = 'imghover';
  var imgHoverLength = imgHover.length;
  var eleArr = [];
  
  $('a').each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');
    if(classes.indexOf(imgHover) >= 0){
      var nextChar = classes.charAt(classes.indexOf(imgHover)+imgHover.length);
      eleArr.push('.'+imgHover+nextChar);
    }
  });
  
  var uniqueClasses = [];
  $.each(eleArr, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueClasses) === -1) uniqueClasses.push(el);
  });
  var eleClass = uniqueClasses.join();

  $(eleClass).hover(
    function(){   
      var $elem = $(this);
      var $elemImg = $(this).children('img');
      $elemImg.removeClass('img-gray'); 
      $elemImg.addClass('img-text-color'); 
      $elemImg.removeClass('no-underline'); 
      $elemImg.css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
      $elemImg.css("transition", "all 0.6s ease-out");
    },
    function(){ 
      var $elem = $(this);
      var $elemImg = $(this).children('img');
      $elemImg.addClass('img-gray');
      $elem.removeClass('img-text-color'); 
      $elem.addClass('no-underline'); 
    }
    );
});
```

```css
.img-gray {
  color: gray;
}
.img-text-color {
  color: red;
}
.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b400ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="imghover1" href="/en/?p=1">one</a>
<a class="imghover2" href="/en/?p=2">two</a>
<a class="imghover3" href="/en/?p=3">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->
<a class="imgval imghover1" href="/en/?p=1"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/one.svg">one</a>
<a class="imgval imghover2" href="/en/?p=2"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/two.svg">two</a>
<a class="imgval imghover3" href="/en/?p=3"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/three.svg">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->

<!-- and more... -->
<a class="other imghover1" href="/en/?p=1"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/one.svg">one</a>
<a class="other imghover2" href="/en/?p=2"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/two.svg">two</a>
<a class="other imghover3" href="/en/?p=3"><img class="img-fluid img-gray rounded" alt="" src="/img/three.svg">three</a>
<!-- and more... -->
```